# which is the best way to implement: two separate array or array in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need an advice!
I have an array of objects with many students data(more then 200 students). So, now, i want to implement lesson for this students, so, every day, i will push an array with data inside every array of students. Later i will work with all lesson data! 
So my question is: 
a) Is the best way to push array inside of every students array?
b) Or make another array with  unique _id, and later filter lesson by students _id?

So, i'm looking for performance and speed...

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your architecture, a suitable option will be moving `lessons` to a separate collection and storing `lesson._id` in `students[].lessons`. You can reach it by using [ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) property in your mongoose schema.

Here's the example:

`lessons` collection data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "First lesson"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "name": "Second lesson"
  }
]
```

`groups` collection data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "name": "Group 1",
    "students": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
        "name": "John",
        "lessons": [ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")]
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
        "name": "James",
        "lessons": [ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"), ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I would also moved every `student` to separate `students` collection if it is possible (if you currently have `students` as array field).

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this is the question, should i use separate collection, or only one?

Comment: @RuslanJackson please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844726/9317057 (nested array vs separate collection). If we talk about short answer, then mine is: use nested array if you 100% sure that lessons will be strictly bound to students and won't be used without them. **But** if we talk about scalability and possibility to update lesson data by changing one document only (and using refs), then I recommend using separater collection. So that's not perfomance issue only.